# Incorrect integer value: '@taxi_id' for column 'taxi_id' at row 1

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm having a problem when I insert a value it will show a error:

> incorrect integer value: "for column 'taxi_id' at row 1

```
string 
insertcmd = "INSERT INTO taxi(taxi_id) VALUES ('@taxi_id')";

myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taxi_id", BigInteger.Parse(merchantId,NumberStyles.Integer));
```

`taxi_id` in database is of type `Bigint(255)`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes, the post needed editing, but you went changing the c# code to just text, and that was very wrong in my opinion. You should have left the code the code. Then it would have been an acceptable edit. @MehdiDehghani

Comment: And please don't downvote my answer if you disagree me rejecting your edit.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using quotes around `@taxi_id`, it is considered a literal textual value and not a parameter.

Remove the quotes so `@taxi_id` becomes a parameter:

```
INSERT INTO taxi(taxi_id) VALUES (@taxi_id)
```